# USACO-beads, unable to debug while loops

Tags: c++

[This](http://train.usaco.org/usacoprob2?a=c9Mxpo8GxxE&S=beads) is the problem that I was working on

I am not getting any compile-time errors, run-time errors, and most of my code seems to work fine. After debugging, I found that the while loops inside the `left()` and `right()` are causing the problem. I am having a hard time figuring out why, so any help would be awesome. thanks.

Just in case--

> **Sample input:**
>
> 29
>
> wwwbbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrb
>
> **Sample output:**
>
> 11

**Code:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int MAXN = 1000000 + 10;
int n;
char cur_beads[MAXN];

//WORKS LIKE A BOSS:
void final_array(int int_in, char * array_in){

    for (int i = 1; i <= int_in; i++){
        cur_beads[n-i] = array_in[int_in - i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n - int_in; i++){
        cur_beads[i] = array_in[int_in+i];
    }
//    cout << "new array, for "<< int_in << " = " <<cur_beads << endl << endl;;
}
//ERROR HERE:
int left(){ //function
    int left_a = 0, left_b = 0, c = 0;

    cout << cur_beads << endl;

    while((cur_beads[c] != 'b' || cur_beads[c] != 'w') &&  c <= n){
        cout << cur_beads[c] << endl;
        c++;
    }
    cout << "c = " << c << endl;
    while((cur_beads[c] == 'b' || cur_beads[c] == 'w')){
        left_b++;
        c++;
    }
    cout << "left_b = " << left_b << endl;

    c = 0;
    while((cur_beads[c] != 'r' || cur_beads[c] != 'w') &&  c <= n){
        c++;
    }
    cout << "c = " << c << endl;

    while(cur_beads[c] == 'r' || cur_beads[c] == 'w'){
        left_a++;
        c++;
    }
    cout << "left_a = " << left_a << endl;

    if (left_a > left_b){
        return left_a;
        cout << "left = " << left_a << endl;
    }
    else{
        return left_b;
        cout << "left = " << left_b << endl;
    }
}
//ERROR HERE:
int right(){ //function
    int right_a = 0, right_b = 0, c = 0;

    while((cur_beads[n-c] != 'b' || cur_beads[n-c] != 'w') &&  c <= n){
        c++;
    }
    while((cur_beads[n-c] == 'b' || cur_beads[n-c] == 'w')){
        right_b++;
        c++;
    }

    c = 0;
    while((cur_beads[n-c] != 'a' || cur_beads[n-c] != 'w') &&  c <= n){
        c++;
    }
    while((cur_beads[n-c] == '' || cur_beads[n-c] == 'w')){
        right_a++;
        c++;
    }

    if (right_a > right_b){
        return right_a;
        cout << "right = " << right_a << endl;
    }
    else{
        return right_b;
        cout << "right = " << right_b << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int ans = 0, current_ans = 0; //stored as 0 by default

    ifstream fin("beads.in");
    ofstream fout("beads.out");

    fin >> n;

    char beads[MAXN];


    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fin >> beads[i];
    }

//    final_array(11, beads);
//    current_ans = left();
//    cout << "current_ans = " << current_ans << endl;


    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){ //main loop
        final_array(i, beads);
        current_ans = left() + right();
        cout << "current_ans = " << current_ans << endl;

        if (current_ans > ans){
            ans = current_ans;
        }
    }

    fout << ans << endl;

}
```

All the cout 's in the `left()` were meant for debugging code.

Comment: _I found that the while loops inside the left() and right() are causing the problem._ What problem? What output do you expect? Isn't `11` correct? Please, describe literally what you observed in the debugger which doesn't match your expectations.

Comment: Please, consider `while((cur_beads[c] != 'r' || cur_beads[c] != 'w') &&  c <= n){`: For every value in a `char c` this is always true: `c != 'r' || c != 'w'`. It cannot be at the same time `'r'` and `'w'`, can't it? IMHO, you meant AND (`&&`) but not OR (`||`). I.e. `while((cur_beads[c] != 'r' && cur_beads[c] != 'w') &&  c <= n){`

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio?

Comment: oh! that makes a lot more sense, thank you so much @Scheff, can't believe i didnt see that before.

Comment: nope this is in codeblocks

Comment: (Too bad. I only know it by name.) Please, have a look for visual debugging. I assume you are using `gcc` as compiler. (It's the default in CodeBlocks.) The debugger is probably `gdb`, and it hopefully has a graphical interface in CodeBlocks. With the visual debugger, you can execute your code step by step. At each step, you can have a look into current variable values. This is much better than print debugging with `cout`. With this, you probably had seen by yourself the failing `while` loop. (Though, I'm glad to see that you attempted any debugging before sending a question...) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
while((cur_beads[c] != 'b' || cur_beads[c] != 'w') &&  c <= n)
```

does not make sense as any character will NOT be both a 'b' and a 'w'. What would make more sense would be to modify this line (and others with this issue) to

```
while((cur_beads[c] != 'b' && cur_beads[c] != 'w') &&  c <= n)
```